# Cassandra restore from snaphot not restoring entire data

Tags: cassandra, backup, datastax, restore

I am trying to implement Cassandra(2.2.6) backup and restore using **nodetool** commands. Currently I have four nodes in Cassandra cluster out of which two are seed nodes with **incremental_backup : enabled**

I have followed below steps for backup and restore on one of the nodes:

1. Creating a snapshot of a keyspace with a sample table:
   `nodetool snapshot testkeyspace`
2. Drop the test table from the given keyspace : `cqlsh> Drop table test`
3. Recreate the schema of the above dropped table
4. Stop the Cassandra service
5. Clear cassandra-commitlog directory
6. Copy the content of backup directory and latest snapshot directory from the old directory of `test` table into the **new** `test` table directory
7. Start Cassandra service
8. Run `nodetool repair`
9. Run `nodetool refresh testkeyspace test`

After the restore when I query the table, some of the records are missing. I am not sure what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried flushing your table before the snapshot? It's not obvious to me that all the data would be in SSTables in this scenario.

Comment: What is the RF (replication factor) of the keyspace with the table you are querying?

Comment: As per the datastax document, Cassandra flushes the node before taking a snapshot. I tried doing it manually still no luck. The RF of the keyspace is 3.

Comment: if you have 4 nodes with RF=3, then each node will have 75% of the data. In other words, snapshot on one node will not have all data.